# Laravel 5.1 - Routes Error - NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller, routes, laravel-5.1

This error happen in my laravel 5.1 project, when trying to access `http://localhost:8000/dashboard.user.update` after I click `Submit` on my `edit` form.

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 143:
```

This error happen when I run `update` function in my controller. I have no error when runing other function like `index` or `show`.

This is my routes:

```
...
// Dashboard routes...
Route::resource('dashboard/user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('dashboard', 'DashboardController');
...
```

I already runs `php artisan route:list` to see if my routes are working:

```
+--------+----------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                   | Name                   | Action                                      | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----------------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------+------------+
...
|        | POST     | dashboard/user        | dashboard.user.store   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store   | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/user        | dashboard.user.index   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index   | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/user/create | dashboard.user.create  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create  | auth       |
|        | DELETE   | dashboard/user/{user} | dashboard.user.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/user/{user} | dashboard.user.show    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show    | auth       |
|        | PUT      | dashboard/user/{user} | dashboard.user.update  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update  | auth       |
|        | PATCH    | dashboard/user/{user} |                        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update  | auth       |
...
```

Now I don't know what to do, can help?

Comment: you should not access the route that way..it should be http://localhost:8000/dashboard/user/id were id is the id of the user

Comment: @JLPuro, yes, `localhost:8000/dashboard/user/user_id` is the way to access when showing the data. I have no error running `localhost:8000/dashboard/user/user_id` to `show`, or `localhost:8000/dashboard/user/user_id/edit` to `edit`. What I need is to `update`.

Comment: @JLPuro, By the way, using `http://localhost:8000/dashboard.user.update` is not my way to access route. The laravel did. That URI show in my browser URL.

Comment: can you pls paste here your form edit specifically the action you are using

Comment: yes, I understand..what I mean is you need to use Post method and use the correct route in your action..like
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/users/11" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Answer (score 0):

Like your routes table says you need PUT or PATCH for an update call. Your route is correct but laravel checks the routes also for the method type.
I think you want to display a view and not return a json (RestAPI) if so than the implicit controllers are much better than resources!

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers

If you want to use them you have to rename your methods to getIndex(), getEdit(), postStore() and if you want post not put than postUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

If it's an update, tell laravel it's a "PUT" request. Since simply POST method for that url with the user_id not exists.

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

Something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/user/1">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
    //...
```